# What values can a constructor return to avoid returning this?

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator

What are the exact circumstances for which a `return` statement in Javascript can return a value other than `this` when a constructor is invoked using the `new` keyword?

Example:

```
function Foo () {
  return something;
}

var foo = new Foo ();
```

If I'm not mistaken, if `something` is a non-function primitive, `this` will be returned. Otherwise `something` is returned. Is this correct?

In other words, what values can `something` take to cause `(new Foo () instanceof Foo) === false`?

Comment: related: [What is returned from a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3350215/1048572)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

The exact condition is described on the `[[Construct]]` internal property, which is used by the [`new`](http://www.interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-11.html#a-11.2.2) operator:

From the ECMA-262 3rd. Edition Specification:

> [13.2.2](http://www.interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-13.html#a-13.2) `[[Construct]]`
>
> When the `[[Construct]]` property for a `Function` object `F` is
>   called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Create a new native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set the [`[[Class]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#_Class_) property of `Result(1)` to `"Object"`.
> 3. Get the value of the prototype property of `F`.
> 4. If `Result(3)` is an object, set the [`[[Prototype]]`](http://www.interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-4.html#a-4.3.5) property of `Result(1)` to `Result(3)`.
> 5. If `Result(3)` is not an object, set the [`[[Prototype]]`](http://www.interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-4.html#a-4.3.5) property of `Result(1)` to the original `Object` prototype object as
>      described in [15.2.3.1](http://www.interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-15.html#a-15.2.3.1).
> 6. Invoke the [`[[Call]]`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.1) property of `F`, providing `Result(1)` as the `this` value and
>      providing the argument list passed into `[[Construct]]` as the
>      argument values.
> 7. If `Type(Result(6))` is
>      `Object` then return `Result(6)`.
> 8. Return `Result(1)`.

Look at steps 7 and 8, the new object will be returned only if the
type of `Result(6)` (the value returned from the `F` constructor
function) is **not** an Object.

Comment: Additional note: typeof(null) is "object", however returning null does *not* trigger step 7 to happen

Comment: @BT: Testing on my node.js installation, it seems like "`Type(x)` is `Object`" in the spec as cited above means "`x instanceof Object` is `true`", *not* "`typeof(x) === 'object'` is `true`". For example, `null instanceof Object` evaluates to false (and indeed you can't return `null` from a constructor), and `new String("asdf") instanceof Object` evaluates to true (and indeed you can return a String from the constructor...)

Comment: @JoSo I think Type refers to an object's internal `[[Class]]` property. The best proxy for that value that we have from within JavaScript is `Object.prototype.toString.call(x)`

Comment: @JoSo: No. It means that `x` is not a primitive value, but an object (including arrays, functions etc). It does have nothing to do with `typeof` or `instanceof`.

Comment: but why null doesn't get returned ?

Comment: @Martian2049, because the internal type of a `null` value is the [Null Type](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-null-type), internally, you may think that is "object" since `typeof null == 'object'`, but that's not what the internal Type operation detects. It will return the object created in step 1 just because internally, the `null` value _internal type_ is Null, not Object.

Answer (score 4):

Concrete examples

```js
/*
ECMA 262 v 5
http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf
"4.3.2
primitive value
member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, Symbol, or String as defined in clause 6"
*/

var Person = function(x){
  return x;
};


console.log(Person.constructor);
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor);
console.log(typeof(Person));
console.log(typeof(Person.prototype));

function log(x){
  console.log(x instanceof Person);
  console.log(typeof x);
  console.log(typeof x.prototype);
}

log(new Person(undefined));
log(new Person(null));
log(new Person(true));
log(new Person(2));
log(new Person(""));

//returns a function not an object
log(new Person(function(){}));


//implementation?
//log(new Person(Symbol('%')));
```

Comment: great example! lll

Comment: just add this: new Person({"stuff":"stuff"})
// {"stuff":"stuff"}

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any documentation on the matter, but I think you're correct. For example, you can return `new Number(5)` from a constructor, but not the literal `5` (which is ignored and `this` is returned instead).

Comment: By the way: this happens because `new Number(5)` (or even just `Number(5)`, as it is intended to work just the same if called as a function) creates a number *object*, for example this means that while `'' == false`, `!!new String('') == true`.

Comment: Two years later and ready to reply to correct my own comment, this works: `function One(){return new Number(1)}` but this doesn't: `function One(){return Number(1)}`

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, the return value or `this` is just part of the equation.

For example, consider this:

```
function Two() { return new Number(2); }
var two = new Two;
two + 2; // 4
two.valueOf = function() { return 3; }
two + 2; // 5
two.valueOf = function() { return '2'; }
two + 2; // '22'
```

As you can see, `.valueOf()` is internally used and can be exploited for fun and profit. You can even create side effects, for example:

```
function AutoIncrementingNumber(start) {
    var n = new Number, val = start || 0;
    n.valueOf = function() { return val++; };
    return n;
}
var auto = new AutoIncrementingNumber(42);
auto + 1; // 43
auto + 1; // 44
auto + 1; // 45
```

I can imagine this must have *some* sort of practical application. And it doesn't have to be explicitly a `Number` either, if you add `.valueOf` to any object it can behave as a number:

```
({valueOf: function() { return Math.random(); }}) + 1; // 1.6451723610516638
```

You can exploit this to make an object that always returns a new GUID, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to put a few points in simpler words.

In javascript, when you use a `new` keyword on a function and if,

1. function does not return anything, it will return an intended object

```js
function User() {
  this.name = 'Virat'
}

var user = new User();
console.log(user.name); //=> 'Virat'
```

2. function returns any **truthy** complex object [object, array, function etc], that complex object takes priority and `user` variable will hold the returned complex object

```js
function User() {
  this.name = 'Virat';
  return function(){};
}

var user = new User();
console.log(user.name); //=> undefined
console.log(user); //=> function
```

3. function returns any literal, constructor takes priority and it will return an intended object

```js
function User() {
  this.name = 'Virat';
  return 10;
}

var user = new User();
console.log(user.name); //=> 'Virat'
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are using the `new` keyword, an object is created. Then the function is called to initialise the object.

There is nothing that the function can do to prevent the object being created, as that is done before the function is called.

Comment: I'm not taking about that. I know you can do what I claim (I've tried it), but I don't know the definitive cases for which it occurs. In my example, it IS possible to end up with `(foo instanceof Foo) === false`.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.