# Return Statement in JS Constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor, return

What is the effect of a return statement in the body of JavaScript function when it's used as a constructor for a new object(with 'new' keyword)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this/

Answer (score 22):

Usually `return` simply exits the constructor. However, if the returned value is an Object, it is used as the `new` expression's value.

Consider:

```
function f() {
   this.x = 1;
   return;
}
alert((new f()).x);
```

displays 1, but

```
function f() {
   this.x = 1;
   return { x: 2};
}
alert((new f()).x);
```

displays 2.

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

The reason to use the `new` operator is to ensure that `this` inside the constructor refers to a *new* context, which supports:

```
this.functionName = function(){...};
```

, and to allow the use of the `instanceof` operator:

```
function foo() {...}
var bar = new foo();
alert(bar instanceof foo);
```

Using `return {...}` inside such a constructor negates both of these effects as `this` will not be needed with such a pattern, and as `instanceof` will return `false`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i think this reveales a drawback of js constructors.