# Javascript class defenition

Tags: javascript, inheritance, class

When the `myClass` function returns a single string "hii", `testClass.getDetails()` works fine:

```
function myClass(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

    return "hii";
}
myClass.prototype.getDetails = function() {
    return "mydetails";
}

var testClass = new myClass('aneesh', 27);
alert(testClass.getDetails());
```

But when I return an object in `myClass`:

```
function myClass(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    return {};
}
```

I get an error:

> testClass.getDetails is not a function

Why does that happen? In Javascript a string is also an object, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor/3350363#3350363

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a string literal like the one you are returning (`"hii"`) is a **primitive value** is not an object.

In JavaScript we have the following primitives: string, number, boolean, undefined and null.

If a constructor used with the `new` operator returns a primitive, the `this` value will be returned.

If an object is returned, like in your second example (which IMO is not really useful), the newly created object (`this` within the constructor) will be lost, and you get an error because it doesn't contain a property named `getDetails`.

For example:

```
function Test () {
  // don't return anything (equivalent to returning undefined)
}

new Test() instanceof Test; // true

function Test2 () {
  return {};
}

new Test2 instanceof Test2; // false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because constructors:

- automatically return the new `this` object if no manual return is specified
- return another object of your choice if returned manually

However, you can't manually return a primitive value from the object, such as a raw string, number or boolean. You can get around this by Object-wrapping the value so that it's actually a String object:

```
return new String("hii");
```