# Why can a constructor only return an object?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, return, instanceof

If there is a constructor like

```
function a() {}
```

then

```
(new a) instanceof a === true
```

---

But on the other hand,

```
function a() { return {} }
```

results in

```
(new a) instanceof a === false
```

---

So what I was thinking is that

```
function a() { return 123 }
```

would result in the same thing. However, when returning a Number,

```
(new a) instanceof a === true
```

---

How is this possible? Why can't I make a constructor return something else than an Object?

(I do know making a constructor returning a Number is rather useless but I would like to understand the 'why' of this behaviour)

Comment: A constructor isn't meant to return an object

Comment: Nitpickery: You can certainly return a `Number`, but not a `number`: `function a() { return new Number(123); }`. The result can even be used as a number (`a() + 1 === 124`), it just won't compare `===` to a true number with its value.

Comment: @Kevin Reid: I see. I guess that's because `Number` is an Object whilst `number` is a primitive. (is that correct?)

Comment: pimvdb: Yes. Usually it is good to avoid the value-wrapper objects as they can cause confusion due to their slightly different semantics. The main place you find them is that a method called on a number has `this instanceof Number`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is returned from a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the spec: If calling the constructor returns an object, then this object is the result of the `new`-expression. If the constructor doesn't return an object (but `undefined` or some other primitive value), the result is the newly created object.

If primitives were allowed, then all constructors would have to explicitly return something (typically "`this`"), otherwise the result would be `undefined` (because the result of a function without a `return` is `undefined`). That would be a needless hassle.

Additionally, it makes sense that `new` can be relied on to always return an object.