# abnormal behavior of 'new' in java-script

Tags: javascript

I have written the exact code in console and the problem which I am facing with this code is:

1. why is xyz.c is defined
2. why abc.count is undefined

code:

```
function setup()
{
   this.count = 0;
   return function() 
    {
       this.c = 1;
       return this.c;
    };
};
var abc = new setup();
abc.count;
//undefined 
var xyz = new abc();
xyz.c;
//1
```

Comment: sorry for that, now i have edited my code.please check it @RGraham

Comment: `new` should only be used with constructors. Constructors don't return functions. `setup` is not a constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is returned from a constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on the `new operator`:

> The object returned by the constructor function *becomes the result of
>   the whole new expression**. If the constructor function doesn't
>   explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>   instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>   choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>   process.)

<sub>*Emphasis mine</sub>

What you're doing here is overriding the default behavior of `new`. Your code equates to the following:

```
var abc = function() 
{
    this.c = 1;
    return this.c;
};
abc.c; // undefined.
```

Even though you've declared `this.c` your `function()` hasn't actually been *executed* at this stage, so `this.c` is still undefined.

Then, you `new` `abc` with the traditional approach, so:

```
var xyz = new function() {
    this.c = 1;
    return this.c;
};
xyz.c === 1; // Works, because you've new'd the function correctly
```

Assuming you're trying to implement a counter object-oriented style function, you could try something like:

```
function setup()
{
   this.count = 0;
   this.increment = function() {
       this.count++;
   }
};
var counter = new setup();
counter.increment();
counter.increment();
console.log(counter.count); // 2
var counter2 = new setup();
counter2.increment();
console.log(counter2.count); // 1
```

Or using prototypal inheritance:

```
function setup() {}
setup.prototype.count = 0;
setup.prototype.increment = function() {
    this.count++;
};
```

Although naming convention would dictate you should call your *class* something like:

```
function Counter() {
    this.value = 0;
    this.increment = function();
}
var first = new Counter();
```

Answer (score 0):

typeof abc is "function" which should be object to access abc.count. I get this error on executing "var xyz = new abc();"

VM40:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined
    at new  (:7:17)
    at :2:11
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (:694:21)

which is not correct.i wonder how you are getting 3?

Comment: sorry for that, now i have edited my code.please check i

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does [prototypical heritage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). You are trying to call a constructor for a function which in turn returns a function.

Try `console.log(setup)` to see what it contains. It's not an object, it has no count property, it's a function. An when you call it via `setup()()` it will always return 1.

What you want could work like this:

```
var Counter = {
    count: 0,
    increaseCount: function() {
         return ++this.count;        
    }
}

var abc = Object.create(Counter);
abc.increaseCount(); // 1
abc.increaseCount(); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see typeof xyz is object ,hence it is accessing the property of the function. and typeof abc is a function. you cannot access a property with function.