# Why does this constructor not return a string?

Tags: javascript, class, instantiation, paradigms

Consider:

```js
function Panda() {
   this.weight = 100;
   return [1,2]; 
}

console.log(new Panda());
```

When we instantiate with `new` keyword (`new Panda()`), it will returns: `[1,2]`

Without return statement, it returns: `{ weight: 100 }`

```js
function Panda() {
   this.weight = 100;
}

console.log(new Panda());
```

With a return statement like: `return "Hello"`, it returns `{ weight: 100 }`

```js
function Panda() {
   this.weight = 100;
   return "Hello"; 
}

console.log(new Panda());
```

Why does it do this? Because is it must be an object?

Comment: It looks like returning a primitive datatype is ignored, but returning an object or array isn't.

Comment: If it's a constructor, why are you trying to return anything?

Comment: @ChrisG maybe the object can be adapted to a structure ("class"), but a primitive datatype just doesn't have indexes that can be associated with data (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: I can ask it different, if it is a constructor why it consider the return value?

Comment: @ChrisG looks like you're [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350364/2315360)

Comment: You can `return Object('Hello')` but I'll be honest, I never knew returning primitives were ignored. Apparently it applies in both strict mode and non strict mode.