# Why does this constructor called method return an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I figued putting the class method inside the constructor would return the `<h1>` but this is not the case.
Instead it returns an object/the class.

Why does it behave this way instead of returning the `<h1>` element?

It seems only doing it this way will it work: `new Foo(data).createText();` ?

```js
const data = "This is a title";


class Foo {
  constructor(data) {
    this._title = data;
    this.createText();
  }

  createText() {
    return `<h1> ${this._title} </h1>`;
  }
}

const targ = document.getElementById('targ');

//Why doesn't this work considering it's called in the constructor?
targ.innerHTML = new Foo(data);

targ.innerHTML += new Foo(data).createText();
```

```html
<div id="targ"></div>
```

Comment: You call `this.createText()` but you don't do anything with the returned value. The whole point of a constructor function is to create instances of a particular kind of object.

Comment: Even if I add a return statement before `this.createText()` in the constructor, it still returns an object. Is this simply the wrong way of doing it and the latter the correct way?

Comment: The constructor cannot return items like that

Comment: Because constructor are intended to behave like that: return an instance of the class, and nothing else ? (what you do inside it, will only have side effects, but always an instance of the class is returned).

Comment: You should probably take some time to research basic object-oriented principles.

Comment: If you just want a function to build a string, then write a plain function. Again, classes are for creating objects. If that's not what you want, don't do it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get why you downvote the question. It's a valid question in search of education.

Comment: @lealceldeiro or an object, any object.

Comment: Why do you think that that would be the expected behavior?  What documentation led you to that conclusion?  What example did you look at to think that this was correct?  Your question lacks research.  There is nothing supporting your idea that that is what should be returned; but there are lots of documentation on using classes that support the contrary as @GetOffMyLawn answer shows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is returned from a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor)

Comment: @zero298 My conclusion had come from the behavior of only using it to set values. I had never used it to call a method and I expected the behavior of it to simply invoke the method and therefor the method return it's own respective data. I intended to use it as a way of _automatically_ invoking it I suppose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a constructor function returns nothing, null, or any atomic / non-object value then said value is ignored and the newly created object reference is given back to the caller. For example, a return value of 0 (zero) from a constructor function will be ignored.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100216124827/http://www.gibdon.com/2008/08/javascript-constructor-return-value.html)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

The default conversion from an object to string is [object Object]

Comment: While factually correct, this has nothing to do with the question?