# Return type of constructor in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

This is the constructor that I am creating in the react-native projects but I want to see what is the return type of it.

```
 Constructor(props){  
     super(props);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You shouldn't return anything in a constructor. A constructor is used to initialize the object. In case you want to know what happens is that if you return 5 then n will simply be an empty object and if you return for example { a: 5 }, then n will have a property a=5

This is already discussion Reff Link: [Construction Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor)

Comment: Thank you for doing this. A constructor is by default returning this.

Comment: Please vote up answer if you got helped. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sure, I can but currently, I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After research and community help. I found that the constructor is returning by default **this**. But you can explicitly send a different object.

**Case First:-**

```
function Test() {
}
var test=new Test();
console.log(test instanceof Test):// output is true
```

**Case Second:-**

```
function OldTest() {
}

function Test() {
    return new OldTest();
}
var test=new Test();
console.log(test instanceof Test);// output is false
```