# Changing the return value of a constructor

Tags: javascript

Based on the JavaScript specification, a class constructor returns the value of `this` when it gets called by the `new` keyword.

Can we change the return value to something else? If yes, is it a bad practice? I'm asking if it is a bad practice, for instance, it could be because of some stuff related to the inheritance. For example

```js
class Car {
  constructor(color) {
    this.color = color
    return this.printColor
  }
  printColor = () => {
    console.log(this.color)
  }
}

const car1 = new Car('red')
car1()
```

Is it a new idea, or is it something normal and the people normally do everyday?

Comment: As you can see, you can, I wouldn't say it's *never* used, but it's really weird and I wouldn't do it because it's confusing

Comment: contructor gives birth a child (object), so returning that is a design choice. And now if you have the choice to destroy it, so say you are returning the organs of a full child.. Does that makes sense think this way..?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, omg no that's really sad. I'll stop using this design now right away. now I'm convinced, thank you for the answers.

Comment: Did you ask this because you want to control the methods/properties in the returned object instead of exposing everything?

Comment: You can't return anything from the class constructor, typescript will yell at you. The default return type of constructor is className itself which TypeScript infers meaning that when you do `new ClassName()` it will help you to create instances of the same class,  The sole purpose of the constructor is to initialize the instance's properties and create an instance of a class.

Comment: As I said the default return type of constructor is className itself, taking this fact into account I once return `new className()` from the constructor and it leads to an error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" because by doing so I'm creating an infinite instance of that class(LOL)

Comment: @Brother58697, no, just because I was writing an npm package, and I thought of this syntax to be used by the client, so instead of him writing `const x = new Car("red").method; x()`, he can directly write `const x = new Car("red"); x()`. because the only method or property my class provides is the `method` method.

Comment: @Normal You can use a function that returns another function like [this](https://jsbin.com/kuqotow/edit?js,console). Like in the second example, you can put more complex implementation inside.

Comment: @Brother58697, I don't have an error, my code is fully working, I'm just asking to know the _why_, and the _opinions_. not to end up in a solution.

Comment: @AnuragTripathi Nobody was asking about TypeScript afaict. But even there, you can `return` a *different* instance than `this` and still have the correct return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A class constructor returns the value of `this` when it gets called by the `new` keyword.

See [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1048572) and [How does the new operator work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6750880/1048572) for details.

> Can we change the return value to something else?

Yes, as long as it is an object, you can override the default by using `return` - as you did in your example code. See [What values can a constructor return to avoid returning this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1978049/1048572) and [What is returned from a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3350215/1048572) for how that works exactly.

> If yes, is it a bad practice?

Yes. Having `new Car` return a function and not a `Car` instance is weird and unexpected. People do not do this every day, and they shouldn't start doing it :-)

The only exception is the singleton pattern (which of course [is problematic itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/137975/1048572)), where the constructor may `return` the singleton instance instead of a new one. (There are however other ways to write JS code for creating singletons, which avoid constructors altogether.)