# Is RETURN from constructor necessary when creating object with new

Tags: javascript, specifications

if I have function like this:

```
function Apple(){
    this.color = "green";
    return this;
}
```

When creating object like this:

```
var my_obj = new Apple();
```

is that line `return this;` necessary and/or is it valid by language reference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What values can a constructor return to avoid returning this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, returning `this` is not necessary, but it is valid. If the returned value is an object, `new` will return that object instead of the newly created object.

See points 11.2.2 and 13.2.2 of [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf):

The new operator calls the internal [[Construct]] method on the constructor (usually a function):

> 11.2.2 The new Operator
>
> The production NewExpression : new NewExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating NewExpression.
> 2. Let constructor be GetValue(ref).
> 3. If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. If constructor does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. **Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on constructor, providing no arguments (that is, an empty list of arguments).**

The [[Construct]] internal method of functions is described in point 13.2.2:

> 13.2.2 [[Construct]]
>
> When the [[Construct]] internal method for a Function object F is called with a possibly empty list of arguments, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let obj be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set all the internal methods of obj as specified in 8.12.
> 3. Set the [[Class]] internal property of obj to "Object".
> 4. Set the [[Extensible]] internal property of obj to true.
> 5. Let proto be the value of calling the [[Get]] internal property of F with argument "prototype".
> 6. If Type(proto) is Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to proto.
> 7. If Type(proto) is not Object, set the [[Prototype]] internal property of obj to the standard built-in Object prototype
>      object as described in 15.2.4.
> 8. Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F, providing obj as the this value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as args.
> 9. **If Type(result) is Object then return result.**
> 10. **Return obj.**

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary, a constructor automatically returns the newly created object.

About explicitly returning a value from constructor this page has good information: [JavaScript: Constructor Return Value](http://www.gibdon.com/2008/08/javascript-constructor-return-value.html)

Quote:

> If a constructor function returns nothing, null, or any atomic / non-object value then said value is ignored and the newly created object reference is given back to the caller. For example, a return value of 0 (zero) from a constructor function will be ignored.

and

> ...the second piece of magic eluded to above is the ability for a constructor to return a specific, possibly pre-existing object, rather than a reference to a new instance. This would allow you to manage the number of actual instances yourself if needed; possibly for reasons of limited resources or whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary.

The function will implicitly return a new `Object` when instantiated with the `new` operator. `this` will refer to that new object in that context.

Invalid returns (such as primitives or non new objects) will still return the standard `this`.

You can override it by returning a new different object.

```
var a = function() {
    return new Number(42);
},

b = new a; // typeof b === 'number'.
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BD2k7/).