# JS Class that return a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, static

So i love this React thingy, and we have this so called 'stateless' functions to help us build a 'dumb' component. Now i want to create a class that produce a stateless function. Why you may ask, well i love the idea of inheritance and wanting to 'extend' my stateless function basic capability, said i want to add a helper function as a statics that binds to the function itself.

I ended up with this code

```
class Stateless {

  constructor() {
    return this.render.bind(this)
  }

  nanny() {
    // do something
  }

  render(props) {
    // yeay! a stateless function!
    // plus i can access nanny by using this.nanny()
  }
}
```

And when i extend it, i can see that the inheritance is working well.
BUT, if then i initialize the class:

```
const stateless = new Stateless()
```

Why can't i access `stateless.nanny` even tho inside the `render` function i can see that `this.nanny` is accessible? Where does the `nanny` lives? Does it binded to the `render` function?

EG:

```
class Stateless {
  constructor() {
    return this.render.bind(this)
  }

  nanny() {
    console.log('foo')
    return true
  }

  render(props) {
    console.log(this.nanny()) // -> returns 'foo'
    return 'JSX'
    // this should return a JSX
  }
}

const stateless = new Stateless() // -> stateless IS a function

stateless()
// 'foo'
// true
// JSX

stateless.nanny
// undefined
```

While clearly inside `render` when i called `this`, there is nanny there. But when i 
refer it outside, the nanny is gone. I thought `nanny` should be a static property of the `stateless`, right?

Comment: If you can give a more concrete case, it would be easy for all of us to help you in a better way.

Comment: I'll elaborate by making an example

Comment: Try `console.log(stateless)`.

Comment: @ceving https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=FDDGBsEMGdoAgDIFMDmB7OBvYBIaAXSfAS1DnwE8AHJOAXjgHJxU1GQdQ0A7AgJwCuofGj4AKAJRZcOPknwC-3cgAti0AHRzuAEyR8NAI2K6x-NdAm4AvhwAKfNFQAq1JPAbY43n5ABccACMwD5wtiE-Kkjg4GiS0qHeXLxoLBqxKGKMUTFsVolwcgpKquoA3BHe4bJIuvrxXonJ0KlI6WiZ5uoaObGS-YlFispdmg5OrjTQMgD0M6qOAO5w3EjLAKJ8juIABgAiGNxo-HAC0LQAJJijGpQ01nA6xHLC4BQAhDtWOLbhAG6QPhwSBoWgMVbLZDoSQVMA8FppDJiEFIfoVZqtdqZFESdHwzFIlE9aKxCRAA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning object from constructor - `new` will return that object instead of the instance of the class being constructed ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064673/is-return-from-constructor-necessary-when-creating-object-with-new)).

Therefore line

```
const stateless = new Stateless()
```

will assign to `stateless` variable result of `this.render.bind(this)` - that is reference to method (function) of Stateless class, that is **not an instance of Stateless**. Therefore `stateless.nanny` makes no sense - as function `render` does not have such property defined. On the other hand calling bound `render` function directly - produce the expected result.

All in all - i strongly do not recommend you to return anything from constructor (unless you are dealing with some really weird requirements like controlling number of instances and such). It makes code hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: Hi Amid, thanks for answering! Now I *intentionally* return this.render because that is what I want. I want `stateless` to be just a function and no more. Since stateless component is a function. Now, can I assume that by doing `new Stateless()` in this way, I have create an instance that is nowhere to be referenced yet part of it still live in `stateless` ? Coz definitely I can access `this.nanny()` inside the `stateless()`

Comment: Exactly - you create instance of Stateless that is not referenced anywhere except from within `render` because you have bound it in constructor. Therefore inside `render` call - `this` is still instance of the Stateless component, otherwise inaccessible outside.

Comment: Cool! An automated closure :D haha.. anyway, do you know any method to kinda *reattach* the `nanny` to the `stateless` from inside the class? I mean, I don't wanna reattach it once the `new` invoked. Thanks

Comment: It gets misleading really fast. In your case you want to reattach `nanny` to `stateless` that is actually reference to `render` method. I do not think its what you really want. Maybe you need pure javascript function object with attached properties instead of class with such a weird constructor.

Comment: Yes, kind of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588563/adding-custom-properties-to-a-function

Comment: Maybe, I am exploring the possibilities here. I just want to be able to call it from outside like a static property of a function. But if that's not possible I wouldn't mind

Answer (score 0):

Your example should work if you remove **this.render.bind(this)** from your constructor.

It should also work, if you just remove **return** from the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.render.bind(this)
}
```

However, you might actually be looking to create a higher order component that can enhance the component that it wraps.

Your higher order component is a function that returns a class that renders the component that it passed to it:

```
import React from 'react'

function HigherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent) {

  return class Enhancer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
    }

    exampleFunc() {
      // Code here
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent exampleprop={ this.exampleFunc } />
    }
  }

}

export default HigherOrderComponent
```

Then you can import HigherOrderComponent into your stateless dumb component file and wrap the export:

```
import React from 'react'
import HigherOrderComponent from './HigherOrderComponent'

const DumbComponent = (props) => {
  // Return JSX
  // You can use props.exampleprop
}

export default HigherOrderComponent(DumbComponent)
```

Here are some articles that you can read on higher order components:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html
https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e

Comment: That kinda beat the purpose I made this class. I want the class to return a function.

Comment: You might be looking to create a higher order component. I have updated my answer.

Comment: No, I don't want an HOC, I want an extendable and inheritable Class that returns a stateless function