# How do I use CoffeeScript to mock out existing code?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, markdowndeep

I'd like mock out MarkdownDeep, I've the following code, in JavaScript

```
MarkdownDeep = new (function () {
    this.Markdown = function () {
        this.Transform = function (a) {
            return "html";
        };
    };
})();
```

but I'm having trouble implementing this in CoffeeScript

I tried the following

```
MarkdownDeep = new (->
  @Markdown = ->
    @Transform = (a) ->
      "html"
)()
window.MarkdownDeep = MarkdownDeep
```

but it doesn't work, specifically in my unit test `markdown = new MarkdownDeep.Markdown()` gives "undefined is not a function", though the JS version mocks out fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example results in the following javascript code:

```
var MarkdownDeep;
MarkdownDeep = new (function() {
  return this.Markdown = function() {
    return this.Transform = function(a) {
      return "html";
    };
  };
});
window.MarkdownDeep = MarkdownDeep;
```

The line `return this.Markdown = function() { /* ... */ }` makes the function the object returned by the `new` operator.

Writing

```
MarkdownDeep = new (->
  @Markdown = ->
    @Transform = (a) ->
      "html"
    return
  return
)
window.MarkdownDeep = MarkdownDeep
```

fixes the problem.

**Addition:**
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this/1978474#1978474) mentions the algorithm for object construction in javascript

Comment: JS constructors can be tricky like this about their return values.

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeScript's implicit returns can lead to mayhem when used in conjunction with `new`. As others have pointed out, you could use explicit returns. Another option is to use `class`, which creates a function (the `constructor`) with no implicit return:

```
MarkdownDeep = new class
  constructor: ->
    @Markdown = class
      constructor: ->
        @Transform = (a) ->
          'html'
```

Of course, that's not very readable in this case, but as a general rule, you'll save yourself headaches by using `class` whenever you use `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly set a return value for your objects/classes or else it will return the member functions when creating a new instance.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/neEp4/114/)

```
MarkdownDeep = new (->
  @Markdown = ->
    @Transform = (a) ->
      "html"
    undefined #return undefined instead of this.Transform
  undefined #return undefined instead of this.Markdown
)

markdown = new MarkdownDeep.Markdown()
alert markdown.Transform()
```

compiles to:

```
var MarkdownDeep, markdown;
MarkdownDeep = new (function() {
  this.Markdown = function() {
    this.Transform = function(a) {
      return "html";
    };
    return;
  };
  return;
});
markdown = new MarkdownDeep.Markdown();
alert(markdown.Transform());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what Coffeescript gives as output

```
var MarkdownDeep;
MarkdownDeep = new (function() {
  return this.Markdown = function() {
    return this.Transform = function(a) {
      return "html";
    };
  };
});
```

The last line in every function is implicitly returned in Coffeescript. Checking this in the console yields MarkdownDeep as

```
function () {
    return this.Transform = function(a) {
        return "html";
    };
}
```

which returns a function that does not have Markdown() as a method.

Answer (score -2):

CoffeeScript automatically wraps each output file in an anonymous function (`(function() { ... })()`). To disable this use the `--bare` or `-b` option when running `coffee`.

Comment: This is the answer to many, many CoffeeScript questions on Stack Overflow... but not this one. :)

Comment: It was worth a try. :) Thanks @Trevor.