# Wrapping javascript constructor function into another function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have a function for creating objects as follows:

```
function person() {
    this.name = "test person";
}
var me = new person();
```

Now I'm planning to wrap this function into another one like this for assertion purposes.

```
function reliable_person() {
    /* do check on params if any*/
    return new person();
}
var me = new reliable_person();
```

Is this a possible approach? I know there are better ways for such checks within the constructor itself, but is this a reliable solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "reliable"? Yes, it'll work, but the `new` in `new reliable_person` is entirely superfluous. `reliable_person` is just a factory function, not an object constructor.

Comment: According to ECMAScript, new operator discards the object it created if the function constructor returns an object. In this case yes it is superfluous. @deceze

Comment: At second snippet `reliable_person` function behaves like a factory pattern so no call with `new` keyword is required when an object is created through `reliable_person()` function.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618722/how-to-return-null-from-a-constructor-called-with-new-in-javascript/#8618792) shows the procedure for creating a `factory function`. I think this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking a function with `new` constructs a new object and uses the given function to initialise the object. Something that's a bit special about this is that if you `return` a non-primitive value, like an object, from that function, that value will be used as the new object instead. Sounds complicated, but what it boils down to is that `reliable_person()` and `new reliable_person()` result in the exact same thing, because you're returning an object from it. So using `new` with that function is pointless.

Removing the superfluous `new` from it, all that's left is a normal function which returns an object (a "factory function"). Yes, that works and is "reliable".

Comment: The reason why I wanted to go with this approach is that, I don't want to disturb the object creation interface (new) for the end user using the function I plan to make.

Comment: Callers would be confused, since they'll receive an object of type `person` instead of `reliable_person`. There's no need to dress something up without purpose. An object is fine, a factory function is fine. Be clear about what each does and what they're used for, period.

Comment: Just as a side note, if you want to make `reliable_person` a constructor, inside `reliable_person`, run `person.call(this)`, and after the definition of the function, set `reliable_person`'s prototype to `person`'s prototype, with `reliable_person.prototype = Object.create(person.prototype)`. Then, `reliable_person` will inherit from `person` and you'll be able to get a `new reliable_person()`