# Object's value and prototype issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a new class, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code:

```
<script>
var myClass = function(arg){
    return new init(arg);
}
var init = function(arg){
    return arg;
}
init.prototype.prop = true;
</script>
```

The problem is that `myClass('foo')` doesn't return `'foo'` as expected. Instead, it returns `init`.
Then I tried this code:

```
var init = function(arg){
    return [arg];//Now init returns an array
}
```

The `myClass('foo')` returns `['foo']`, but then `myClass('foo').prop` turns into `undefined`. Does anyone know how to solve it?

EDIT: I want to create this class more or less as jQuery does.
For example: `$('div')` returns directly a value (in case, all div tags), but not an object with a property that stores this values

Comment: Do you really want the constructor to return the same value you passed in?

Comment: It's just an example. It could return a number multiplied by 2, for example

Comment: @MarkLinus `$('div')` doesn't return a value, it returns an object

Comment: Whatever, I want to return this object, however, not with literal properties, but with numeric properties (to work like an array) and with method/properties that can be declared by .prototype

Comment: While I don't really understand what you're after, if you want to return the string from the call to `new init(arg)`, you can do so as a String object wrapper. `return new String(arg);` Though overriding the object being created seems to defeat the purpose of `new`.

Comment: @MarkLinus—jQuery returns a "jQuery" object that has a nubmer of methods and properties, one of which is a (possibly empty) array of elements.

Comment: @amnotiam I tried it, but wasn't exaclty what I expected.

Comment: And @RobG, yes, that's what I mean. I want to return this "custom" object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `new init()` and within `init()` you return a non-object, it yields an instance of `init` instead of the returned value.

If you return an Array from your `init()` function, it gets returned instead; but Array doesn't take your `init` prototype into consideration :)

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1978474/1338292

If you want to be like an array, you can do this:

```
function myClass(arg) {
    return new init(arg);
}
function init(arg) {
    this.push(arg);
}
init.prototype = [];
init.prototype.foo = true;

var x = new init('foo');
console.log(x) // ["foo"]
console.log(x.foo) // true
```

It makes `init` inherit from the `Array` prototype (i.e. `[]`). After that you can add more properties and methods to the `init` prototype as you wish.

Comment: That's the point, `x` returns `init`, but I want it to return `['foo','bar']`

Comment: @MarkLinus when you `console.log()` a jQuery return value, it will show `jQuery.fn.init` and underneath you will see the array of dom elements

Comment: Yes, `x[0]` works fine. But I didn't see `jQuery.fn.init` when I `console.log()` the jQuery value

Comment: @MarkLinus when I do this on SO - `console.log($('div'))` - I see `e.fn.e.init[217]`. In any case, I've updated my answer, take a look

Comment: Thank you guy, it was exactly what I was looking for in the last 3 months and now worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

In you code:

```
> <script>
> var myClass = function(arg) {
>   return new init(arg);
> }
> var init = function(arg){
>   return arg;
> }
>
> init.prototype.prop = true;
> </script>
>
```

> The problem is that myClass('foo') doesn't return 'foo' as expected. Instead,
>   it returns init. Then I tried this code:

Your code may be clearer if written as function declarations (which is more common):

```
function myClass(arg) {
  return new init(arg);
}

function init(arg) {
  return arg;
}
```

When you call `myClass('foo')`, you pass a string to `init`, which is called as a constructor. The function then attempts to return the string, however a function called as a constructor will always return an object. If you try to return a primitive, it will instead return its *this* object. It's not very clearly stated in [ECMA-262](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.2). but it is there.

> Then I tried this code:
>
> var init = function(arg) {
>      return [arg]; //Now init returns an array

Because an array is an object, so that is what is returned.

```
> }
>
```

> The myClass('foo') returns ['foo'], but then myClass('foo').prop 
>   turns into undefined. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Because your constructor returns an array, not its *this* object. The returned array inherits from `Array.prototype`, not `init.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

If you return a value from a function and try to use the `new` keyword with it, the return value will not be a newly instantiated object, but rather the value following the `return`.  So in your case the 'foo' string is being returned, not a new object as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but now it throws `TypeError: string is not a function`

Comment: I'm not sure how you got that.  Functions are classes.  If you intend to create an instance of `myClass`, you shouldn't be using `return` in the function (or at least not with a return value).  What you have above is a function that returns an instance of `init`, except that it doesn't; it returns the original argument instead.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain better what I want. Please take a look on it

Comment: @Steve—Not true about the return statement. A function called as a constructor **always** returns an object. If you try to return a string (or any other non–object), it will instead return its *this* object.

Comment: @RobG -- ack, you're right, although I could swear I've seen some browser exhibit that behavior at some point, but maybe I'm thinking of object literals.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new class, you might want to consider this pattern:

```
var MyClass =function(arg) {
    this.init(arg);
};
MyClass.prototype = {
    init: function(arg) {
        // Do something with that arg
        this.someArg = arg;
    },
    myProperty: 'Hell world',
    someArg: null   
};

var myVar = new MyClass('Some arg');
```

Test is out:

```
console.log(myVar.myProperty);
console.log(myVar.someArg);
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/4zwpm/

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't return the directly as I want. Isn't there any other solution?