# The new Operator

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to write a javascript function that follows this (valid) typescript interface:

```
interface Foo{
    // constructor: 
    new (): string; 
}
```

i.e. Something that when called with a new operator returns a string. e.g. the following will not work.

```
function foo(){
    return "something";
} 
var x = new foo(); 
// x is now foo (and not string) whether you like it or not :)
```

Comment: [ECMAScript 5, Sect. 13.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) has this to say about the return value of a constructor that constructs an object `obj` and returns `result`: "*If `Type(result)` is `Object` then return `result`. [Otherwise,] return `obj`.*" Thus, non-object return values cannot be returned from a constructor.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks +1 the comment, If you post as answer I will plus 1 that as well (for the ecma spec link + quote). But for marking as answer rob answered first :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
function foo(){
    return new String("something");
} 
var x = new foo(); 

console.log(x);
```

You can return any object, but literals don't work. See here: [What values can a constructor return to avoid returning this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this)

Comment: Awesome +1. It works. Now I am curious why `new String("string")` works but "string" does not?

Comment: Because string is a primitive, and String is an object type that represents string.  The real question is "Why would you want to do this in the first place?" Using the new operator is intended to create instances of the function's return object. Why would you need many instances of your string value?

Comment: @JoelCochran Yes I know: `typeof "string" == 'string'` not object. http://jsfiddle.net/3mbeQ/

Comment: Sorry @RobH: my response was to BASarat's question in the preceding comment.

Answer (score 2):

ECMAScript 5's [Section 13.2.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) (on the `[[Construct]]` internal property) has this to say about the return value of a constructor:

> 1) Let `obj` be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
>
> ...
>
> 8) Let `result` be the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal property of `F`, providing `obj` as the `this` value and providing the argument list passed into `[[Construct]]` as args.
>
> 9) If `Type(result)` is `Object` then return `result`.
>
> 10) Return `obj`.

Thus, the return value of a constructor can only be an object. A string primitive like `"foo"` has a `Type` result of `String` rather than `Object`. This means that step 9 is false, so step 10 returns the constructed object, instead of the return value of the constructor function.

Instead, you must return an object (`new String("foo")`), as detailed in RobH's answer.

Comment: as promised +1. Thanks for your time. Love the glider logo btw :)

Comment: @BASarat Thanks :) I think RobH is the right answer to accept here; I just wanted to address your "*why `new String("string")` works but `"string"` does not?*" question with the appropriate spec reference.