# JavaScript Class Best Practice?

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I'm currently looking into different patterns for building classes in JavaScript. But no matther what pattern I see, there are still some things I am not really sure about.

```
var ItemManager = (function()
{
    var p = function()
    {
        this.items= [];
    };

    p.prototype.addItem = function(item)
    {
        var self = this;    
        self.items.push(item);
    };

    return p;
}());
```

I create the simple class *ItemManager*, this class got the function *addItem* for adding any item to the collection. Now I don't really want the variable items, which represents the collection, to be public, this variable should be private, but I don't see any possible way to use a prototyped method to access private variables.

So what's the best practice in this case? Simply don't use private variables?

Comment: Obligatory there are no classes in js call

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/436120/1117720

Answer (score 6):

```
var ItemManager = function() {
    var items = [];

    return {
           addItem : function(item) {   
               items.push(item);
           },
           removeItem : function() {
                return items.pop();
           }
     }
};

var myItemManager = new ItemManager();
```

`items` variable becomes hidden after the execution of `ItemManager` function, but `addItem` and `removeItem` still share the access to `items`. See the [Douglas Crockford's article](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) on private variables in JavaScript for further investigation.

Comment: In addition to the comment above: this would create a new set of anonymous functions (assigned to `addItem` and `removeItem` properties) for every separated object.

Comment: @Passerby yeah, I see it... I'll try to find out why. thanks for your comment.

Comment: @aga: that's easy - because on every constructor call you're returning a new object

Comment: @zerkms take a look at the following piece of code: `var a = []; a instanceOf Array;` Here I create a new object, but it's still instance of `Array`. Why does it work?

Comment: That's basically the way I did it until today, but the problem with this pattern ist, that you cannot inherit it and as stated before it will always create a new object. But thank you!

Comment: @aga: because you're creating an instance of `Array` type object. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/1978474/251311 for details

Answer (score 1):

There are [several ways](https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript) to have private variables:

- Closures, as in aga's example, which uses the [Revealing Module Pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript). If you're using ES6 classes, you can [hide private data in the constructor](http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/private-data-classes.html), though it looks pretty ugly to me.
- [ES6] Symbols
- [ES6] WeakMap

I favor Symbols, though they can still be found using reflection (i.e. not completely private). Example:

```
var Person = (function() {
    var nameSymbol = Symbol('name');
​
    function Person(name) {
        this[nameSymbol] = name;
    }
​
    Person.prototype.getName = function() {
        return this[nameSymbol];
    };
​
    return Person;
}());
```

So it's possible to have (reasonably) private variables, but unfortunately none of the solutions are as elegant as you'd like.

Answer (score -1):

as GoldenerAal mentioned, they are not called classes, but functions
you have

```
var ItemManager = function (){
..
...
...

};
```

you could have:

```
function ItemManager(){
this.items = [];

function addItem(item){
...
};
};
```

you can then create an instance of ItemManager, only when you need to :

```
var itemManager = new ItemManager();
itemManager.addItem(<something here>);
```

http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html
variables inside a function only have the scope of that function, that variable is not a global variable (static variable).