# Setting AngularJS controller property cannot be last line using Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm using Coffeescript and am trying to define a controller which will
use the "HomeController as homeCtrl" syntax.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]).controller("HomeController", ->

    @someArray = []

    # return
)
```

This is broken - the `scope.homeCtrl` is set as `[]` rather than the object `{someArray: []}`. I realize this is because Coffeescript automatically returns the last line of a function, so the transpiled `return this.someArray = []` returns `[]` for the function. I can fix this by uncommenting the bare `return` command, or even something like `return true` or `@baz='foobar'`. But the really weird part is that this only messes up when the last line of the function returns an array. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem was killing me! It's actually not only just arrays. Just make it a habit to return at the end of your controllers.

EDIT: to be more specific. It's angular calls the function as a Constructor using the **new** keyword. Constructor behaviour is specified as specified in [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this/1978474#1978474)

Comment: Yeah that's the solution for sure. I was interested in why it does that, however.

Comment: @StevenClontz It's because angular uses the 'new' keyword on the function. Since it's a constructor, the return value is the instance, so returning anything else makes javascript think thats your instance. Omitting a return value returns 'this' which would be the controller itself. Since coffeescript is auto-returning, we're left with that behaviour :)

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CoffeeScript `class` keyword to force CS to create a class constructor:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]).controller "HomeController", class
  constructor: ->
    @someArray = []
```

Or, you could create named class and then pass it to angular.js:

```
class HomeController
  constructor: ->
    @someArray = []

angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]).controller "HomeController", HomeController
```