# React ES6: you may have forgotten to define `render`

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I stuck for a while ,and do not know where is wrong ,Please help me

Here is the error message:

```
Warning: App(...): No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render`.
Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function
```

here is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log('Start')

export class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     console.log('getInitialState');
     return { status:true }
  }
  toggleState(){
    this.setState({status: !this.state.status})
  }
  render() {
    console.log('render');
        return (
           <div>
              <h1 onClick={this.toggleState}>Hello</h1>
           </div>
        );
     }

} 

ReactDOM.render(<App name='Vipul' />,document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `return` from `constructor`, and `state` must be as a property like so

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { status: true };
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39928/)

Look at these two examples

```js
function App() {
   return { status: true }
}
App.prototype.render = function() {};
console.log(typeof new App().render);
```

```js
function App() {
  this.state = { status: true };
}
App.prototype.render = function() {};

console.log(typeof new App().render);
```

as you can see in console you get in first example `undefined` it is because constructor `App` [`returns new custom object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this), and in second you get right result;

Comment: Wow that's a gotcha... so in JavaScript if you return something from a constructor(), it swaps that for the object. Tricky bug, lucky found your solution thanks!