# How to make JavaScript code to work using ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The result of the following code is - undefined:

```
function f() {
    this.a = 1;
    return function() {
        console.log(this.a);
    };
}
(new f)();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What values can a constructor return to avoid returning this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this). When you return functions in a constructor, the result will be that function, not an object holding the `this` value, so `this.a` won’t be defined.

Comment: Is `(new f)()` ever a valid syntax?

Comment: @Amy Yes, the parentheses with `new` are optional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback . Also, this class seems to be semantically incorrect. There's no reason for it to be newed and use `this`

Comment: It's a tricky interview question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking how to convert your anonymous function into an arrow function:

```js
function f() {
    this.a = 1;
    return () => {
        console.log(this.a);
    };
}
(new f)();
```