# Creating Custom Error: Understanding MDN Example

Tags: javascript, error-handling

The below example of how to create a custom Error in JS can be found on MDN ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)).

I am struggling to understand what is going on (specific questions below).

```js
function CustomError(foo, message, fileName, lineNumber) {
  var instance = new Error(message, fileName, lineNumber);
  instance.foo = foo;
  Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, Object.getPrototypeOf(this));
  if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(instance, CustomError);
  }
  return instance;
}

CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: Error,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});

if (Object.setPrototypeOf) {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(CustomError, Error);
} else {
  CustomError.__proto__ = Error;
}


try {
  throw new CustomError('baz', 'bazMessage');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.foo); //baz
  console.log(e.message); //bazMessage
}
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Since we are returning an object inside `CustomError`, will using it as a *constructor* function (`new CustomError()`) and using it as a normal function object (`CustomError()`) yield the same outcome?
2. In line 11: Do we create a new object here, instead of setting `CustomError.prototype` directly to `Error.prototype`, so that we can extend the prototype without affecting all other `Error` objects?
3. Also in line 11: Why do we even bother setting `prototype` property of the function, if we cannot use it as a *constructor* function (ref. question 1)?
4. In line 4 we set the `Error` `instance` to whatever called the function, right? I don't understand what the purpose is / what the `this` value will be.
5. What is the purpose of the `captureStackTrace` check?

Thank you for helping me analyze and understand this snippet.

---

### **EDIT:**

I wanted to add that I think I have understood the following:

- Whenever we create a new object with a *constructor* function (`new` keyword), it gets prototype-linked to an empty object, which in turn is prototype linked to `Object.prototype`
- It is prototype linked to a new empty object, instead of directly to `Object.prototype`, because that way we can extend the prototype of the new object, without changing the behavior of all objects with `Object.prototype` on its prototype chain.
- If we have two levels of "inheritance", and thus manually change the `prototype` property of a *constructor* function, it should reflect the same behavior. In effect, we should set the `prototype` property to be an empty object, which in turn is prototype linked to our newly introduced "parent"

Example:

```js
function Person(name, gender) {
  this.name = name;
  this.gender = gender;
}

function Male(name) {
  Person.call(this, name, "male");
}

Male.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: Male,
    enumerable: false,
    writeable: true
  }
});

var person1 = new Male("Chris");
```

- As seen above, when changing the `prototype` property manually, we should not only assign a new empty object to the `prototype` property, but also set the `constructor` property of that empty object
- This is because every object should indeed be able to look at its prototype to figure out what object constructed it. This follows the behavior of `Object.prototype`, where the `constructor` property is `Object` (same with other built-ins)

That should explain the second block. Have I understood that part correctly?

Comment: 4th and 5th in the second list are true, but I couldn't get what you meant on third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When using `CustomError` as normal function the value of `this` is `undefined` inside it. But if it is used as constructor function `this` will refer to current instance. Considering `this` is passed to `getPrototypeOf`, calling it as normal function will throw error and break the code. But it would be the same if `CustomError` was imlemented like below:

   ```
   function CustomError(){
       if(!(this instanceof MyError)) return new CustomError();
   }
   ```
2. That's exactly like you think
3. I am not sure why you think it can't be used as constructor function because it has already been called with `new` keyword in `try/catch` statement
4. In line 4 `instance`'s prototype is set to the prototype of `this`. `this` refers to current instance of `CustomError` since it's been called via `new`.
5. Since `Error.captureStackTrace` is not supported by all environments (afaik only chrome and nodejs supports it), it checks if the function exists before using it.

---

**Edit part**

- Whenever we create a new object with a constructor function (new keyword), it gets prototype-linked to **`Person.prototype`** (at least has `consctructor` property), which in turn is prototype linked to Object.prototype
- It is prototype linked to **`Person.prototype`**, because `Person` constructor created it and constructors link newly created objects to their own prototype objects. Yes you can change `Person.prototype` without affecting `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks Hikmat, I will spend some time digesting what you wrote, then follow up with any questions. Regarding your "edit part", yep I totally follow you. I just wanted to highlight the additional fact that constructor functions `Male` and `Female` might both use `Person.prototype` as their *prototypal object*, but because we set `Male.prototype` and `Female.prototype` to an empty object prototype linked to `Person.prototype` (with `Create.object()`), instead of setting it directly to `Person.prototype`, we ensure that we can change the prototype for `Male`, without affecting `Female`.

Comment: I thought that if we return an object in a constructor function, any use of `this` to refer to a newly created object is ignored (i.e. the constructor function will work just like a normal function). Is that the wrong understanding?

Comment: If you call a function with `new` kewword, that function has access to `this` regardless of what is going on inside function.

Comment: Hikmat, I have been researching this a bit, and it seems that if we return an object from a constructor function, it no longer works the way you would expect a constructor function to work. Instead of assigning `this` to the new object, then returning it, it will just return the object from the `return` statement, like any other function. See: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm, and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this

Comment: This as well: https://web.archive.org/web/20100216124827/http://www.gibdon.com/2008/08/javascript-constructor-return-value.html

Comment: You are absolutely right about what will be the value of `new A()` e.g. But what I am saying is completely different. Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8gknrd. As you can see the function returns an array but still has access to 'real' `this` before returning which is the case in `CustomError`;

Comment: Hikmat, sorry for the massive delay, will close this one off as soon as possible. Thanks for that live snippet, I see that the function still has access to `this` as if it was a new object. That leads me to a follow-up question: Since it is already prototype linked to `Error`, why not just return `this` (i.e. no return statement) the normal constructor way, and thus avoid creating a new `Error` `instance` inside `CustomError`?

Comment: I am not sure on this, but I think the reason is because it's shorter to use `Error` constructor to create an object  that has non-enumerable `message`, `fileName`, `lineNumber` properties than defining same named properties with same configuration on `this`

Answer (score 1):

`Error()` is a beast.
When its constructor is called, it simply ignores `this` and creates a new Error object.
Normally, one would use `Error.call(this,...)` to have the new subclass instance initialized for its superclass bofore initializing its own modifications. However, with Error, this will fail, as you'll get an initialized new Error object returned and the actual instance remains unaltered. Error() simply ignores its `this` and always creates a new instance.
To circumvent this, a new Error has to be created, then its prototype needs to be changed to the custom prototype (derived from Error.prototype) and this instance is returned, throwing away the instance that was created by the initial new, like Error does (so we have to copy this bad behavior of Error throughout all subclasses).

The following works:

```
MyErrorr = function() { // Class MyError
    var prototype = Object.create (Error.prototype, { name: {writable: false, enumerable: true, value: "MyError"}});
    function MyError (reason, callee) {
        if(reason instanceof MyError)
            return new MyError(reason.message); // clone
        // creating an Error is a bit tricky, as Error.call(this, message) behaves like new Error(message), creating a new instance
        var instance = new Error(reason);
        if(Error.captureStackTrace)
            Error.captureStackTrace(instance, callee?callee:MyError); // exclude the callee or at least MyError() from the stack trace
        var stack = instance.stack; // force creation of the stack output before the prototype is switched (else the formatting is different, no idea why)
        if(Object.setPrototypeOf)
            Object.setPrototypeOf(instance, prototype);
        else
            instance.__proto__ = prototype;
        return instance;
    };
    prototype.constructor = ConversionError;
    MyError.prototype = prototype;
    return MyError;
}();
```

Since 'this' is not used, MyError can be instantiated with and without using `new` (just like `Error`)

There's a problem though:
All those existent Error types are actually instances of the same Error class, not subclasses of Error. At least on Chrome. Also, some functions are part of Error and not of Error.prototype, so they are not available in your class (like captureStackTrace). Maybe it works if you clone them.