# Prevent Javascript constructor from creating new instance if certain argument isn't provided?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to prevent the constructor from instantiating new object, if an argument is not provided.Also in that case i like to return null. But the constructor is creating an object instance even thought i'm returning null.

```
class SampleClass {
  constructor(someArg){
    if(someArg){
      return new SampleClass();
    }
    else{
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const sampleClass = new SampleClass();
console.log(sampleClass);
```

Comment: so throw an error?

Comment: @epascarello isnt it possible to return null ?

Comment: just return; without passing anything @DevDesignerSid

Comment: @Kevin.a can u elaborate... pls

Comment: No, you can’t return `null` from a constructor invoked via `new`. A `new` expression *will* result in some sort of object, never `null`.

Comment: There is nothing in the constructor that will prevent you from making an instance. If the argument is required, throw an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that; a constructor can't return null. See [What values can a constructor return to avoid returning this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978049/what-values-can-a-constructor-return-to-avoid-returning-this).

What you can do is create a factory method that will return `null`. See below. Your question shows you ignoring the argument if it's provided but I assumed you'd want to use it, so I made that change. See below.

```js
class SampleClass {
  constructor(someArg){
    this.someArg = someArg;
  }

  static create(someArg) {
    return (someArg) ? new SampleClass(someArg) : null;
  }
}

const willBeNull = SampleClass.create();
console.log(willBeNull);
const willNotBeNull = SampleClass.create("foo");
console.log(willNotBeNull);
```

You can also throw an error, as some commenters suggested:

```js
class SampleClass {
  constructor(someArg){
    if (!someArg) throw new TypeError("an argument is required");
    this.someArg = someArg;
  }
}

const sampleClass = new SampleClass("foo");
console.log(sampleClass);
try {
  const willError = new SampleClass();
  // below console.log will not be reached
  console.log(willError);
} catch(e) {
  // instead we will catch the error here
  console.log(e.stack);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to combine both approaches: throw an error in the constructor, *and* add a null-returning factory function. (The only problem with this is the duplicated validation logic).